# VC6 and odd WINVER message during compile

Tags: visual-c++-6, platform-sdk

I get the following message in a VC6 project compile:

> OTE: WINVER has been defined as 0x0500 or greater which enables
>   Windows NT 5.0 and Windows 98 features. When these headers were released,
>   Windows NT 5.0 beta 1 and Windows 98 beta 2.1 were the current versions.
>   For this release when WINVER is defined as 0x0500 or greater, you can only
>   build beta or test applications.  To build a retail application,
>   set WINVER to 0x0400 or visit http://www.microsoft.com/msdn/sdk
>   to see if retail Windows NT 5.0 or Windows 98 headers are available.
>   See the SDK release notes for more information.

Any idea what is going on?

It builds and links fine.

I have VC6, VS2005 and 2008 on my XP machine.

Perhaps my Platform SDK is not up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message you're seeing is from the Platform SDK that was supplied with the Visual C++ 6.0 installation, which it seems dates from when Windows 2000 was in beta.

If your application requires `WINVER` to be `0x0500`, and you still need to use Visual C++ 6.0, I would recommend that you install a more recent Platform SDK. According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mapo/archive/2007/06/07/last-platform-sdk-compatible-with-visual-studio-6-0.aspx), the most recent Platform SDK that is compatible with Visual C++ 6.0 is the February 2003 edition. (There's another post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2006/06/20/640172.aspx) that may be useful.)

A word of caution, though - I don't know whether the February 2003 Platform SDK will coexist with your Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 installations.

Answer (score 0):

Or VC6's include path doesn't include your SDK and it's only using the ones that came with VC6.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the latest VC6 Service pack?